# Appium shows InspectorMoved

Tags: python-3.x, appium, appium-android, python-appium, appium-java

[image]

I do have latest version of Inspector installed but it still says inspectorMoved, maybe inspector is not synced with Appium.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

The Inspector is now separated.
You can get it from here https://github.com/appium/appium-inspector/releases